# Why does $(p \oplus q) \land (p \oplus r)$ imply $p \oplus (q \land r)$ but not other way around

Tags: discrete-mathematics, examples-counterexamples, boolean-algebra

I want to know a counterexample to show that the statement above is not true the other way around

So a counterexample for the statement

$p \oplus (q \land r) \implies (p \oplus q) \land (p \oplus r)$

To show is is not true.

Comment: Make a truth table. Your formula has only three variables, so your truth table will have only 8 rows. In at least one of those rows the formula will be false. Your counterexample is that row.

Comment: @MJD How can you tell from a truth table that one implies the other? Because if the truth values match don't both imply each other?

Comment: Make the table for 
$p \oplus (q \land r) \implies (p \oplus q) \land (p \oplus r)$.  This tells you which values of $p,q,r$ make the implication false.  These are your counterexamples.

Answer (score 3):

been a while since I did logic, but

```
p = true, q = true, r = false

LLHS: T xor (T and F) = T xor F = T
RHS: (T xor T) and (T xor F )=F and T = F
```